# How to reference/open a window in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to get a reference to the single window in my app. If I tick off "Visible at launch" it shows up.

I keep seeing code like the following but that doesn't make much sense. How would self know about a window in a nib file if its not declared anywhere in the interface?

```cocoa
NSWindow *window = [self window];
```

When I run that in applicationDidFinishLaunching, I get this error:

```
No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'window'
```

That makes sense, because no interface is declared. Yet how is the window loading automatically when 'Visible at launch' is ticked?

My end goal is that I need to reference a window and change its level, i.e.

```cocoa
[window setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel];
```

Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is:

In AppDelegate.h, declare a "window" property:

```
 @property (strong) IBOutlet NSWindow* window;
```

In MainMenu.nib, connect your main window to the "window" property of "AppDelegate":

> Right-click on the "AppDelegate" object, then click on the widget next to the "window" property and drag it to your window.

Your "AppDelegate" instance will now have a "window" property, and it will be assigned to your main window.

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime I ended up just creating a new project and copying code over. I had tried adding that code before you answered to the original project but didn't know about connecting the delegate.